# Turn Off PhpMyAdmin Autologout

Tags: phpmyadmin, mamp

I have just moved over to Apple and I installed MAMP to replace WAMP that I usually work with on Windows, but now I have lost my config settings obviously and I'm struggling to do it with MAMP.

First I really want to turn off the PHPMyAdmin's autologout after 1440sec of idle time, also I don't really want to log in every time. In wamp I just made my root password blank and set the login to false in the config file.

I have read up online and tried a few things but I cant seem to find the files necessary to change.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config file needs this code and it should resolve your both the issues.

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; 
$i = 0;
$i++;
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
```

Comment: Which config file do I paste this into?

Comment: _config.inc.php_ under _phpmyadmin_ directory